# Regarding installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to download the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. I first downloaded Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 from `https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` . Running it does not give me the option of installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any previous versions of VS can no longer be installed with the VS installer. Here's a link Microsoft's page for older VS versions: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see that this question has been changed to 2017 instead the previously mentioned 2014. If you actually meant 2017 then I don't understand the question, as your screenshot shows 2017 already installed.